# Selecting two coordinates of minimum slope difference

Tags: ruby

and I'm trying to make a function that can sort out 
the two coordinates of minimum slope difference.

To be specific,
Input data are:

1. **`standard_dot`(one array)**  e.g. [0,0]
2. **`other_dots`(one array composed of 7 arrays)** e.g. [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8]]

And the function 'calculate_min_dif' does next things:

1. **Calculate slopes between `standard_dot` and 7 dots in the array `other_dots`**.
2. **Choose a set of 2 dots whose slopes are the closest to each other**.
3. **Return the index of those 2 dots in the array.**

```ruby
   def calculate_min_dif(standard_dot, other_dots)
       index = 0
       slope_list = Array.new(7)

       other_dots.each do |dot|
           slope_list[index] = (( standard_dot[1]-dot[1] ) / (standard_dot[0]-dot[0] )).abs
           index = index + 1
       end

       result = slope_list.index(slope_list.combination(2).min_by { |a,b| (a-b).abs })
       return  result
    end
```

And the Compiler says **the problem is in line6**

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
(repl):6:in `-'
(repl):6:in `block in calculate_min_dif'
(repl):6:in `combination'
(repl):6:in `each'
(repl):6:in `min_by'
(repl):6:in `calculate_min_dif'
```

which means the right side of the `-`, the value of `b` is `nil`
and I cannot figure out why...

Sorry if I'm being too stupid. I'm new to Ruby and English (kind of..)
Thanxx

Comment: There are few issues I see in the code.
Looks like `standard_dot` is not an array but when you are iterating over `other_dots` you have `standard_dot[1]` which is incorrect. It should be `standard_dot`. Also when you iterate `other_dots` you dont again have to do `dot[1]`, you can simply use `dot`

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I figure at least 10% or readers will not understand it. Can you please provide the data that caused the reported exception and also tell us which line of code produced the exception. Please do so by editing your question.

Comment: @PamioSolanky Actually  `standard_dot` is also an array. Sorry for the poor explanation. I've edited my question. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that as follows. I will leave it to others to explain why you are getting the error message.

```
base_pt = [0,0]
pts = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8]]

def slope((x,y), (bpt_x, bpt_y))
  ((y - bpt_y).to_f/(x - bpt_x)).round(5)
end

def slope_diff(pt1, pt2, base_pt)
  (slope(pt1, base_pt)-slope(pt2, base_pt)).abs
end

pts.combination(2).min_by { |pt1, pt2| slope_diff(pt1, pt2, base_pt) }
  #=> [[6, 7], [7, 8]]
```

Let's check that against the slopes.

```
pts.each_with_object({}) { |pt, h| h[pt] = slope(pt, base_pt).round(5) }
  #=> {[1, 2]=>2.0, [2, 3]=>1.5, [3, 4]=>1.33333, [4, 5]=>1.25,
  #    [5, 6]=>1.2, [6, 7]=>1.16667, [7, 8]=>1.14286}
```

You can see that the lines that go through `base_pt` and the points `[6, 7]` and `[7, 8]` have the smallest absolute difference in slopes.